# How to get single cell value of first date greater than X

Tags: excel-formula

I have data like the following:

- Excel version 365 for Enterprise
- A formatted as Date
- B-D are numeric.
- J44 is =TODAY() (currently
  11/9/2021)

What I would like is to get the value from D on the single row that is the first row whos date is >= today.

I have tried =Match and =Index with varying degrees of failure.

This seems like it would have should have chosen the range after but fails using 0 or 1 as return type and with or without MAX:

```
=MATCH(MAX(IF($A$31:$A$38<=TODAY())*$A$31:$A$38),$A$31:$A$38,0)
```

---

This returns **1/2/1900**

```
=MATCH(J44,A31:A38,1) //j44 == =TODAY() (currently 11/9/2021)
```

---

This returns **#N/A**

```
=MATCH(J44,A31:A38,0) //j44 == =TODAY() (currently 11/9/2021)
```

[image: My data]

Comment: what version of excel do you have?

Comment: Office 365 for enterprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match returns the relative location not the value.  You need to wrap it in INDEX to return the relative value:

```
=INDEX($D$31:$D$38,MATCH(MIN(IF($A$31:$A$38>=TODAY(),$A$31:$A$38)),$A$31:$A$38,0)
```

Depending on version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter

With Office 365:

```
=INDEX(SORT(FILTER(A:D,A:A>=TODAY()),1,1),1,4)
```

Comment: This is farther than I have been.  O365 formula gives me the value for 10/31/2021 [214.71]. So close, thanks. I need to get the 11/15/2021 value of [183.04].

Comment: then you have your logic backwards.  today is the 9th and your logic pulls the max date that is less than today.  It seems you want the min date that is greater than today.  Is that correct?

Comment: @JoeJohnston see edit.